# Can't get my android virtual device that uses android 4.2.2 to load

Tags: android

I'm using Android 4.2.2 and I'm trying to get my Android Virtual Device to work. Here is a snapshot of the set-up of my AVD:

[image]

I have the system image files that are needed to create the AVD. When I try to launch the AVD, I get the following error:

[image]

I have enabled the "user host GPU" option, and I still have the same problem. I can only get the word "ANDROID" to come up? Could someone make some suggestions as to what the source of the problem is? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your PC might not be supporting the graphics.
Try using the Snapshots launch. That'd take some time on the initial launch but it will launch pretty soon thereafter on the subsequent launches. I hope that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks user2320244, I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: Good Luck. I think it will solve the purpose. You might, if you have the resources setup use some small screeen avd's as well.. Cause they take very less time to launch.

Comment: Hi user23020244, I tried you solution and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Did you try changing the emulator?

Comment: Yes, I have. Waiting on it to load up now. I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: I'm still having problems. Could you give me anymore suggestions?